# Not able to turn off springboot 2 logs from application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I've created a microservice using spring boot 2.0 and Oracle as backend. When i call stored procedure I'm seeing a lot of unwanted thing in my logs.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call STORED_PROCEDURE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}]; SQL state [72000]; error code [20503]; ORA-20503: Invalid or unknown client
ORA-06512: at "STORED_PROCEDURE", line 11943
ORA-06512: at "STORED_PROCEDURE", line 13757
ORA-06512: at line 1
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20503: Invalid or unknown client
ORA-06512: at "STORED_PROCEDURE", line 11943
ORA-06512: at "STORED_PROCEDURE", line 13757
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Here the exception is thrown twice with two different class 1. org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException, 2. java.sql.SQLException

**1. How to prevent this duplicates**

I am seeing a lot of unwanted exception from spring.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle
.....
....
```

I tried turning it off using the following log level in application.properties but still getting logs from org.springframework.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
logging.level.com.mypackage=DEBUG
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: It isn’t duplicated, that is the full stack trace. Fix the actual error, to resolve it.

Comment: The log messages you see are telling this; "Hey, there is an error.  You must fix this error."  You can pretend that there is not an error, but that will never make the error go away.

Comment: My program is working perfectly if I try with proper input. If i try with wrong input, I'm getting the exception. It is thrown from Oracle Store procedure. I cannot control users from providing wrong data. I just provided the first 5 lines. I am getting around 200 lines. I just want to show only my custom exceptions in logs and not Springframework logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the logs by adding **logback.xml** in the resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %thread %logger{1} 
                %m%n%rEx{full,
                java.lang.reflect.Method,
                org.apache.catalina,
                org.apache.tomcat,
                org.springframework.aop,
                org.springframework.security,
                org.springframework.transaction,
                org.springframework.web,
                org.springframework.cglib,
                org.springframework.jdbc,
                org.springframework.dao,
                org.springframework.boot.actuate,
                oracle.jdbc.driver,
                org.apache.coyote,
                java.util.concurrent,
                com.zaxxer.hikari.pool,
                javax.servlet.http,
                sun.reflect
                }
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```